# json data not showing in a table generated by js

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a variable from php in js like:

```
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($json_array) ?>;
```

and I am trying to pass this obj's keys and values to a table generated by javascript. myData format in console is pasted below.
and when I pass it to the table, I get a error saying it can not read 
myData. I know I can pass the data as an object but somehow this is different since I brought in from php and is not reading it like a regular json file. Error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null
at generateTable?

what myData outputs in the console:

```
0:
Carat: "0.70"
Clarity: "VVS2"
Color: "D"
Cut: "Very Good"
Polish: "Fair"
Price: "2806"
Product ID: "17"
Product Name: "0.7 Carat Cushion Diamond"
Report: "IGI"
Shape: "Cushion"
Symmetry: "Ideal"
purl: "http://klaussongs.com/product/0-7-carat-cushion-diamond/"
__proto__: Object
1: {Product ID: "19", Product Name: "0.9 Carat Round Diamond", Carat: "0.90", Clarity: "VS2", Shape: "Round", …}
2: {Product ID: "21", Product Name: "1 Carat Radiant Diamond", Carat: "1.00", Clarity: "SI1", Shape: "Radiant", …}
3: {Product ID: "23", Product Name: "1.15 Carat Princess Diamond", Carat: "1.15", Clarity: "IF", Shape: "Princess", …}
```

functions to generate the table from myData:

```
function generateTableHead(table, data) {
          let thead = table.createTHead();
          let row = thead.insertRow();
          for (let key of data) {
            let th = document.createElement("th");
            let text = document.createTextNode(key);
            th.appendChild(text);
            row.appendChild(th);
          }
        }

        function generateTable(table, data) {
          for (let element of data) {
            let row = table.insertRow();
            for (key in element) {
              let cell = row.insertCell();
              let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
              cell.appendChild(text);
            }
          }
        }


        let table = document.querySelector("table");


        let data = Object.keys(myData);


        // generate cells from values
        generateTable(table, myData);


        // create heading from keys
        generateTableHead(table, data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this `let table = document.querySelector("table");` is returning null. Are you sure that the table element has been created at the time this query is run? Can you confirm that this returns null?

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me figured it out. I had to move script to make it work.